# Kafka + SSL: General SSLEngine problem for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate

I am trying to configure kafka with SSL but when I start kafka, then I get this error:

```
[2019-08-12 12:28:15,506] INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9093. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2019-08-12 12:28:17,014] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:85)
    at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:726)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:367)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addDataPlaneProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.addDataPlaneProcessors(SocketServer.scala:260)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:223)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:220)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:220)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:120)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:255)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.startup(SupportedServerStartable.java:114)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:66)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:71)
    ... 17 more
[2019-08-12 12:28:17,017] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

This is what I have done:

```
- 1) Create a Certificate Authority. The generated CA is a public-private key pair and certificate used to sign other certificates. A CA is responsible for signing certificates.
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -x509 -subj "/CN=Kafka-Security-CA" -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -nodes

- 2) Create a kafka broker certificate:
keytool -genkey -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -validity 365 -storepass serversecret -keypass serversecret -dname "CN=localhost" -storetype pkcs12

- 3) Get the signed version of the certificate:
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -certreq -file cert-file -storepass serversecret -keypass serversecret

- 4) Sign the certificate with the CA:
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:serversecret

- 5) Create a truststore by importing the CA public certificate so that the kafka broker is trusting all certificates which has been issued by our CA:
keytool -keystore kafka.server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass serversecret -keypass serversecret -noprompt

- 6) Import the signed certificate in the keystore:
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass serversecret -keypass serversecret -noprompt

- 7) Configure server.properties:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

ssl.keystore.location=/home/xrobot/confluent-5.3.0-community/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=serversecret
ssl.key.password=serversecret
ssl.truststore.location=/home/xrobot/confluent-5.3.0-community/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=serversecret

security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
```

EDIT:
I removed https from "ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https" and now I get this error:

```
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:os.version=4.15.0-55-generic (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:user.name=xrobot (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/xrobot (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,083] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/xrobot/confluent-5.3.0-community (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,084] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@8dbdac1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,096] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,104] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,106] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,176] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,180] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,236] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000dd1939b0001, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,242] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,261] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1000dd1939b0001, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,375] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:32,375] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:33,504] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:33,505] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:33,508] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:33,511] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000dd1939b0001, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:33,516] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1000dd1939b0001, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:33,617] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:33,618] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:34,823] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:34,824] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:34,825] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:34,829] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000dd1939b0001, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:34,833] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1000dd1939b0001, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:34,934] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:34,934] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:36,769] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:36,770] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:36,771] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:36,774] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000dd1939b0001, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:36,778] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1000dd1939b0001, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-08-13 17:58:36,879] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-08-13 17:58:36,879] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
^C[2019-08-13 17:58:37,292] INFO Terminating process due to signal SIGINT (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2019-08-13 17:58:37,294] INFO Shutting down SupportedServerStartable (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2019-08-13 17:58:37,294] INFO Closing BaseMetricsReporter (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)
[2019-08-13 17:58:37,295] INFO Waiting for metrics thread to exit (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2019-08-13 17:58:37,295] INFO Shutting down KafkaServer (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2019-08-13 17:58:37,297] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-08-13 17:58:37,304] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer shutdown. (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kafka server is still starting up, cannot shut down!
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:584)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.shutdown(SupportedServerStartable.java:147)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka$1.run(SupportedKafka.java:62)
[2019-08-13 17:58:37,305] ERROR Caught exception when trying to shut down KafkaServer. Exiting forcefully. (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kafka server is still starting up, cannot shut down!
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:584)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.shutdown(SupportedServerStartable.java:147)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka$1.run(SupportedKafka.java:62)
xrobot@xrobot:~/confluent-5.3.0-community$
```

Comment: ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=        keep null value and try , remove https

Comment: @RamanaMuttana Done. Now I get another error. See above please :)

Comment: can you provide your zookeeper.jaas .conf  file , as per my understanding you have to use only kreberos or Digest-MD5 , try to use DigestLoginModule inspite of other in zookeeper.jaas .conf

Comment: you have missed this step in doing based on my observation::::  keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed  :: you did not imported the signed certificate in to the keystore , you only imported the public key in to keystore , after 6 th step follow the command what i mentioned and run the server again from beginning , https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/security_tutorial.html#generating-keys-certs    check the steps in this blog and your sixth step

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "-keyalg RSA" to p.2 like this:

```
- 2) Create a kafka broker certificate:
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -validity 365 -storepass serversecret -keypass serversecret -dname "CN=localhost" -storetype pkcs12
```

then you should add server cert to server.keystore in p.6:

```
- 6) Import the signed certificate in the keystore:

    keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass serversecret -keypass serversecret -noprompt
    keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file cert-signed -storepass serversecret -keypass serversecret -noprompt
```

As server keystore needs to keep it for serving clients.

And note this:

```
#From kafka 2.0 onwards, host name verification of servers is enabled by default and the errors were logged because,
#the kafka hostname didnt match the certificate CN. If your hostname and certificate doesnt match,
#then you can disable the hostname verification by setting the property ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm to empty string
```

keep it empty for testing:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
```

you should make changes to your /etc/hosts and give server FQDN name, have it in DNS for correct work with clients, or add to every client /etc/hosts IP with FQDN of your kafka - as it is necessarily for Kafka.